# How to add parameters to resource boundle

Tags: jsf-2, myfaces, trinidad

I'm trying this (that works):

```
   message = Any value {0}

   <h:outputFormat id="myMessage" value="#{bundle.message}">  
       <f:param value="#{mybena.value}"/> 
   </h:outputFormat>
```

Trinidad :

```
   <tr:outputText id="myMessage" value="#{bundle.message}">  
       <f:param value="#{mybena.value}"/>
   </tr:outputText>
```

it does not work. I am using TRINIDAD components and I want use parameters like in JSF

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your question is confusing and contains too much red herrings and typos. 1) It doesn't work with `<h:outputText>` at all. It works only with `<h:outputFormat>`. 2) The bundle key is `bunle.message` but you used `message`. This would never have worked, you should have used `#{bundle['bunle.message']}`. Please formulate the question with more care and respect!

Comment: respect? Have I offended anyone? I made a mistake just asking my question because my level of English language is not very good.

Comment: No, you have provided untested code. This has nothing to do with your command of English.

Comment: As per your edit: your statement is still incorrect. It does not work with `<h:outputText>` at all. Why do you keep posting incorrect/untested code?

Comment: The "ustested code" was a copy and paste error when trying to ask the question. Sorry for the inconvenience ...

Answer (score 0):

Not using trinidad, but a possible workaround might be :

```
<tr:outputText id="myMessage"> 
   <h:outputFormat value="#{bundle.message}" > 
     <f:param value="#{mybena.value}"/>
   </h:outputFormat> 
</tr:outputText>
```

Comment: did you used `h:outputFormat` and not `h:outputText` ?

Comment: i am using Trinidad components, not JSF

Comment: How exactly is the `<h:outputFormat>` insufficient? Why exactly do you need a Trinidad variant of it? What problem exactly are you trying to solve this way?

Comment: I'm just trying to ask if there is any way to pass parameters with the Trinidad components as does the JSF